# How to see if the first character of an inputfile is a number? C programming

Tags: c, fopen

```
void main()
{
    FILE *fp1;
    char ch;
    int count = 0;

    fp1 =  fopen("Text.txt","r");
    if(fp1==NULL){
        printf("Failed to open file. Bye\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Text file exists");
    fclose(fp1);

}
```

example of an input file(Text.txt)-

```
3
nameA
nameB
nameC
```

I would like to check if the very first character of this input file is a number. If its missing a number than program will stop

Comment: You already have the file opening. How about you read a character (fread) and check it's value?

Comment: How you do it depends somewhat on what you want to do if it *is* a number. Personally, I'd read in a line from the file with `fgets` (beware that it leaves the newline at the end of the line), then check the first character of that line (or perhaps check that all characters are digits, or perhaps allow there to be extra whitespace at the beginning of the line,...). Then you might use `sscanf` to scan the digits as an integer.

Comment: `Failed to open file.` is a terrible error message.  What was the reason for the failure?  Try `if(fp1==NULL){perror("Text.txt");exit(1);}`

Answer (score 1):

Include ctype.h and then there are functions that do type checks. Alternatively check if the value of the char is in the appropriate ASCII range.

Answer (score 1):

This would solve your problem

```
void main()
{
    FILE *fp1;
    char ch;
    int count = 0;
    fp1 =  fopen("Text.txt","r");

    if(fp1==NULL){
        printf("Failed to open file. Bye\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Text file exists");
    ch = fgetc(fp1);
    if (ch < '0' || ch > '9') {
        fclose(fp1);
        printf("Exit: First character is not a number\n");
        return;          // first character of the input file is not number so exit
    }

    fclose(fp1);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you close the file before exiting?

Comment: @santosh main()
I would like to display a message when no number is found.

Comment: @user3456889 after fclose inside the if condition you can add your printf statement before return. Added in the edit

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fp1;
    char ch, line[128];
    int count = 0, num;

    fp1 =  fopen("Text.txt","r");
    if(fp1==NULL){
        printf("Failed to open file. Bye\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Text file exists\n");
    if(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp1)){
        if(1==sscanf(line, "%d", &num)){
            while(num-- && fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp1)){
                printf("%s", line);
            }
        } else {
            printf("The beginning of the file is not numeric. Bye\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    } else {
        printf("No contents of the file. Bye\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fclose(fp1);
    return 0;
}
```